# What happens if you give a Destiny Knot to a female pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

What happens if you give a Destiny Knot to a female pokemon? For example, if you have a female 5IV Talonflame and a 4IV male Fletchinder, will the IVs still be passed down?

EDIT: Does it matter which parent you give the Destiny Knot to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/index.php?title=In-battle_effect_item&redirect=no#Other_items) states:

> If **Destiny Knot** is held by a Pokémon in Day Care, five of the parents' combined twelve IVs will be passed down to the child.

So no, it doesn't matter which parent holds it.
What's important in breeding is that the parent with the Nature you want to pass down has to held a *Everstone*. So the other one will necessarily held *Destiny Knot*.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/696959-pokemon-x/answers/362357-how-exactly-does-the-destiny-knot-work) information provides a correct and detailed answer in relation to how the Destiny Knot works with breeding:

> When you breed, you have 3 possibilities for the IV of each stat for
>   the baby. The first is that the child will have the mother's IV for
>   that stat, the second is that it will have the father's, and the third
>   is that it will randomly choose an IV for that stat. When breeding
>   without the knot, three of the IVs will be inherited from the parents.
>   So if you have a set of 6 IV parents, the child might inherit the HP
>   and Def from the mother and the Sp. Atk from the father, resulting in
>   a 31/x/31/31/x/x child. With the destiny knot, five are passed down
>   instead of three. In the example, we might inherit the Sp. Def and
>   Speed from the father as well, resulting in a 31/x/31/31/31/31 child.
>
> They don't pool. If a stat is passed down, it goes to that same stat,
>   i.e. if the mother's HP is passed down, the child's HP will match the
>   mother's. It won't go to a different stat or be added to a total
>   amount to be distributed between stats.

Comment: Does it matter which parent is holding the destiny knot?

Comment: From MY own experience, I've found that, as you say, having the female hold it to be more beneficial. I'll see if I can find some solid evidence to back this claim up, though.

Comment: Further from my answer - It doesn't appear that it has any effect on the offspring regardless of who you place the Destiny Knot on.